# How to do PostgreSQL function like FOR JSON, OPENJSON in MS SQL Server?

Tags: json, postgresql

I migrate DB from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
     DTL_CODE
    ,DTL_NAME_ENG
FROM DATA_LIST
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

[image]

```
[{"DTL_CODE":"F","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Female"},{"DTL_CODE":"M","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Male"}]
```

And

```
SELECT
    *
FROM OPENJSON('[{"DTL_CODE":"F","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Female"},{"DTL_CODE":"M","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Male"}]')
WITH (
     DTL_CODE varchar(25)
    ,DTL_NAME_ENG varchar(255)
)
```

Result:

[image]

How to do in PostgreSQL?

I am just start PostgreSQL, I try to find solution but result 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_array_elements`

```
select j->>'DTL_CODE' as dtl_code,
       j->>'DTL_NAME_ENG' as dtl_name_eng
from json_array_elements(
    '[{"DTL_CODE":"F","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Female"},
      {"DTL_CODE":"M","DTL_NAME_ENG":"Male"}]') as j;
```

To do the reverse, use `json_agg` and `json_build_object`

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('DTL_CODE', 
                dtl_code,'DTL_NAME_ENG' , dtl_name_eng))
from t
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a6b81e29dcaa0b48f1cebdac653efa8a)

Comment: Thank you!  But how to select * into json array?

Comment: @Sophairk : Check Edits

Comment: @Sophairk: please do not expand the scope of your question once you have an answer. One question per question please. If you have a new question, then please ask a new question (you can link back to this one if you want)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't expand question, he just edit answer. understand?

Comment: @Sophairk: "*But how to select * into json array" is something different than your original question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name different word but they are the same. please check question and check edit answer.

Comment: I ask FOR JSON & OPENJSON but first time he answer only OPENJSON, I reply one more FOR JSON, after he edit answer to full.